# How to handle inbound stream cancellation in Spring Boot RSocket Reactive

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, reactor, rsocket

## Goal

I want to have an RSocket channel endpoint in my Spring Boot application in which I can handle the cancellation of the inbound, client-driven stream to do some server side cleanup.

## Setup

Relevant dependencies:

- Spring Boot 2.4.2
- Kotlin 1.4.21
- Kotlinx Coroutines 1.4.2
- RSocket Core 1.1.0

I have tried to achieve my goal with both Kotlin coroutine Flows and Reactor Flux(en?). Both client/server pairs below should do the same thing: establish an RSocket channel, send 2 "ping" payloads from the client, the server responds to each with a "pong" payload, and the client closes the connection.

Flow server side:

```
    @MessageMapping("testFlow")
    fun testPingFlow(input: Flow<String>): Flow<String> {
        val cs = CoroutineScope(EmptyCoroutineContext)
        val output = MutableSharedFlow<String>(10)

        cs.launch {
            try {
                input
                    .catch { e ->
                        logger.error("Rsocket server input error", e)
                    }
                    .onCompletion { exception ->
                        logger.debug("Rsocket server input completed")
                        if (exception != null) {
                            logger.error("Exception received while processing Rsocket server input flow", exception)
                        }
                    }
                    // Normal .collect complains about being internal-only
                    .collectIndexed { _, message ->
                        logger.debug("Rsocket server input received $message")
                        output.emit("pong ${System.currentTimeMillis()}")
                    }
            } catch (e: Throwable) {
                logger.error("Rsocket server input connection exception caught", e)
            }
        }
        return output
    }
```

Flow client side test:

```
    @Test
    fun testPingFlow() {
        val outToServer = MutableSharedFlow<String>(10)

        runBlocking {
            val socketFlow = rSocketRequester
                .route("testFlow")
                .data(outToServer.asFlux())
                .retrieveFlow<String>()
                .take(2)

            outToServer.emit("Ping ${System.currentTimeMillis()}")
            outToServer.emit("Ping ${System.currentTimeMillis()}")

            socketFlow
                .onCompletion { exception ->
                    logger.debug("Rsocket client output completed")
                    if (exception != null) {
                        logger.error("Exception received while processing Rsocket client output flow", exception)
                    }
                }
                .collect { message ->
                    logger.debug("Received pong from server $message")
                }
        }
    }
```

Flux server side:

```
    @MessageMapping("testFlux")
    fun testPingFlux(input: Flux<String>): Flux<String> {
        val output = Sinks.many().unicast().onBackpressureBuffer<String>()
        try {
            input
                .doOnNext { message ->
                    logger.debug("Rsocket server input message received $message")
                }
                .doOnError { e ->
                    logger.error("Rsocket server input connection error", e)
                }
                .doOnCancel {
                    logger.debug("Rsocket server input cancelled")
                }
                .doOnComplete {
                    logger.debug("Rsocket server input completed")
                }
                .subscribe { message ->
                    output.tryEmitNext("pong ${System.currentTimeMillis()}")
                }
        } catch (e: Throwable) {
            logger.error("Rsocket server input connection exception caught", e)
        }
        return output.asFlux()
    }
```

Flux client side test:

```
    @Test
    fun testPingFlux() {
        val outToServer = Sinks.many().unicast().onBackpressureBuffer<String>()

        rSocketRequester
            .route("testFlux")
            .data(outToServer.asFlux())
            .retrieveFlux<String>()
            .doOnCancel {
                logger.debug("Rsocket client output connection completed")
            }
            .doOnError { e ->
                logger.error("Exception received while processing Rsocket client output flow", e)
            }
            .take(2)
            .subscribe { message ->
                logger.debug("Received pong from server $message")
            }

        outToServer.tryEmitNext("Ping ${System.currentTimeMillis()}")
        outToServer.tryEmitNext("Ping ${System.currentTimeMillis()}")
    }
```

## The Problem

Both client/server snippets above do in fact send ping/pong payloads back and forth, but in each case I get no handling on the server side of the client cancelling the connection. I get my own log line of `Rsocket client output completed` from the client side, then `Operator called default onErrorDropped` from Reactor and the following stack trace from RSocket:

```
java.util.concurrent.CancellationException: Inbound has been canceled
    at io.rsocket.core.RequestChannelResponderSubscriber.tryTerminate(RequestChannelResponderSubscriber.java:357) ~[rsocket-core-1.1.0.jar:na]
    at io.rsocket.core.RequestChannelResponderSubscriber.handleCancel(RequestChannelResponderSubscriber.java:345) ~[rsocket-core-1.1.0.jar:na]
    at io.rsocket.core.RSocketResponder.handleFrame(RSocketResponder.java:217) ~[rsocket-core-1.1.0.jar:na]
    at reactor.core.publisher.LambdaSubscriber.onNext(LambdaSubscriber.java:160) ~[reactor-core-3.4.2.jar:3.4.2]
    at org.springframework.security.test.context.support.ReactorContextTestExecutionListener$DelegateTestExecutionListener$SecuritySubContext.onNext(ReactorContextTestExecutionListener.java:120) ~[spring-security-test-5.4.2.jar:5.4.2]
    at io.rsocket.core.ClientServerInputMultiplexer$InternalDuplexConnection.onNext(ClientServerInputMultiplexer.java:248) ~[rsocket-core-1.1.0.jar:na]
    at io.rsocket.core.ClientServerInputMultiplexer.onNext(ClientServerInputMultiplexer.java:129) ~[rsocket-core-1.1.0.jar:na]
    at io.rsocket.core.ClientServerInputMultiplexer.onNext(ClientServerInputMultiplexer.java:48) ~[rsocket-core-1.1.0.jar:na]
    at io.rsocket.core.SetupHandlingDuplexConnection.onNext(SetupHandlingDuplexConnection.java:118) ~[rsocket-core-1.1.0.jar:na]
    at io.rsocket.core.SetupHandlingDuplexConnection.onNext(SetupHandlingDuplexConnection.java:19) ~[rsocket-core-1.1.0.jar:na]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapSubscriber.onNext(FluxMap.java:120) ~[reactor-core-3.4.2.jar:3.4.2]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapSubscriber.onNext(FluxMap.java:120) ~[reactor-core-3.4.2.jar:3.4.2]
    at reactor.netty.channel.FluxReceive.drainReceiver(FluxReceive.java:267) ~[reactor-netty-core-1.0.3.jar:1.0.3]
    at reactor.netty.channel.FluxReceive.onInboundNext(FluxReceive.java:377) ~[reactor-netty-core-1.0.3.jar:1.0.3]
    at reactor.netty.channel.ChannelOperations.onInboundNext(ChannelOperations.java:381) ~[reactor-netty-core-1.0.3.jar:1.0.3]
    at reactor.netty.channel.ChannelOperationsHandler.channelRead(ChannelOperationsHandler.java:94) ~[reactor-netty-core-1.0.3.jar:1.0.3]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379) ~[netty-transport-4.1.58.Final.jar:4.1.58.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365) ~[netty-transport-4.1.58.Final.jar:4.1.58.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357) ~[netty-transport-4.1.58.Final.jar:4.1.58.Final]
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.fireChannelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:324) ~[netty-codec-4.1.58.Final.jar:4.1.58.Final]
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:296) ~[netty-codec-4.1.58.Final.jar:4.1.58.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379) ~[netty-transport-4.1.58.Final.jar:4.1.58.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365) ~[netty-transport-4.1.58.Final.jar:4.1.58.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357) ~[netty-transport-4.1.58.Final.jar:4.1.58.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1410) ~[netty-transport-4.1.58.Final.jar:4.1.58.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379) ~[netty-transport-4.1.58.Final.jar:4.1.58.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365) ~[netty-transport-4.1.58.Final.jar:4.1.58.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:919) ~[netty-transport-4.1.58.Final.jar:4.1.58.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:166) ~[netty-transport-4.1.58.Final.jar:4.1.58.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:719) ~[netty-transport-4.1.58.Final.jar:4.1.58.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:655) ~[netty-transport-4.1.58.Final.jar:4.1.58.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:581) ~[netty-transport-4.1.58.Final.jar:4.1.58.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:493) ~[netty-transport-4.1.58.Final.jar:4.1.58.Final]
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:989) ~[netty-common-4.1.58.Final.jar:4.1.58.Final]
    at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74) ~[netty-common-4.1.58.Final.jar:4.1.58.Final]
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30) ~[netty-common-4.1.58.Final.jar:4.1.58.Final]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832) ~[na:na]
```

This is a problem as (beyond this toy example) my application needs to do server-side cleanup on connection close.

## Things I Have Tried Unsuccessfully

- All the various methods to catch exceptions, cancellation, or completion on Flows or Fluxen, many of which are illustrated in the example above.
- try/catch blocks in the subscribe/collect lambdas.
- Coupling the server response Flux/Flow directly to the input Flux/Flow via a map operator rather than creating a separate output Flux/Flow.
- Stepping through framework code in the debugger, which I am not ashamed to say lost me pretty quickly. My best theory from this adventure is that the Flux/Flow that receives the cancellation signal is somehow decoupled from the input Flux/Flow that my server method receives, but there are too many layers of abstraction for me to trace it.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: sounds like a bug needed to be reported at the https://github.com/rsocket/rsocket-java. Will appreciate it if you can do that

Comment: @OlehDokuka it seems to be there already: https://github.com/rsocket/rsocket-java/issues/960

Comment: Then I misunderstood you. If your onError signal is being propagated to your `input`, then - all good, and what you see should be fixed in the next patch release

Comment: Yep.  Both the Flow and Flux server examples look correct.  You should be able to use normal cancellation/completion signals in both frameworks to achieve what you are trying to do.  There should definitely not be a "here is how to handle cancellation with rsocket" documentation here.

Comment: @OlehDokuka thanks for the response. I've tried 1.1.1-SNAPSHOT as described [here](https://github.com/rsocket/rsocket-java/issues/960). It catches or suppresses the "Inbound has been canceled" exception, but I still don't receive any error, cancellation, or completion signals in either of my server side snippets (which is what I need to clean up server side resources). Should I report a bug to the `rsocket-java` project?

Comment: it is a bug in the reactor `switchOnFirst` operator which does not propagate an inbound error if outbound has been canceled. I recommend you to fill a bug report in spring framework github and I will followup from there

Comment: @OlehDokuka [done](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/26520)

Comment: Awesome! I propose to close that one rather then keeping it as a question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Bug filed](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/26520), marking this question as answered. Thanks to everyone for the quick responses.